# How can I attach different signatures to individual emails using the same account in Evolution?

Tags: evolution, email, customization, signature, personalization

I currently have Gmail set up as my default account with Evolution.  I have various signatures that I would like to use and select prior to sending specific emails.  Is there a way to:

1. Create a signature that isn't associated with a specific account
2. Have the option to attach a specific signature, or no signature at all.

Currently I have a work signature, a joke signature, a "Sent from Ubuntu" signature, and a couple of social network signatures.  Some of these are appropriate, but I wouldn't want to attach one of my joke signatures on a work email. Sometimes all I want to do is just send the email without a signature.

Is there a way to do this using Evolution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I get to answer my own question. This is actually a bug with evolution and v10.10
[Here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1591131&highlight=evolution+signatures) are a couple of work arounds that helped.

The problem occurred when updating from v10.4 to v10.10. Apparently this is considered a severe bug for business use of evolution.

Below is a screen shot with the problem. Note that the "From" line is missing. This also contains the signature dropdown selector.
[image]

The [link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1591131&highlight=evolution+signatures) above describes setting up another email account using none@none as the email address. This is illustrated below.
[image]

The result does allow for the "From" and "Signature" form element to be displayed and accessed.
[image]

Now if I could only get some Reputation for my great answer! [image]

Comment: You should mention the bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/evolution/+bug/649609 and that it is already fixed. The fix can be tested by enabling the proposed archive: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Testing/EnableProposed

Comment: Someone else has already mentioned the bug report.